# How to set text on the node in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-browser

I want to set the text on the node

I have a example,node is created,but it is bare in graph,only a circle without a text.

```
 merge(n1 {label:'me'})
 return n1
```

I expect a text on the node.
actually,result is like this:
[bare node image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyqqJ.png)

what I expected is:
[node with text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tT34e.png)

I know I can creat a node with text like this:

```
MERGE (michael:Person { name: 'Michael Douglas' })
RETURN michael
```

Text will be Michael Douglas [node with name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahe78.png)

But if I change it to:

```
MERGE (michael:Person { name1: 'Michael Douglas' })
RETURN michael
```

No text! [no text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d77wG.png)

or:

```
MERGE (michael:Event { name: 'Michael Douglas' })
RETURN michael
```

Text is a number 35 [number text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaDVW.png)

So what is the principle of setting text?Why sometimes it will use the name of person,sometimes it is a number of internal id?sometimes it is bare?

Are there some rules?some document to tell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neo4j Browser comes with visual tool.

The fact that nodes displayed with different properties you see is just visual guide, completely unrelated to the Neo4j itself.

In the docs: [Neo4j Browser Style Guide](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/#_styling_neo4j_browser_visualization)

> The nodes will already have sensible captions assigned by the browser, which auto-selects a property from the property list to use as a caption. You can see all the properties of that element if you click on any node or relationship. Properties will appear below the visualization. Larger property sets might be collapsed into a subset, but there is a little triangle on the right to unfold them.

The Neo4j Browser will pick a "suitable" property to display. So it's usual to see `name` property is displayed but `name1` is not.

To manually select a property to display:

1. Select the node (in the upper bar of the result view, not in the view)
2. Select the field you want to display as `captions` (in the lower bar)

[image]